# Why do apache2 upgrades remove and not re-install libapache2-mod-php5?

Tags: apt, apache2, php

We repeatedly see that when an apache2 update arrives and is installed it causes the libapache2-mod-php5 package to be removed and does not subsequently re-install it automatically.

We must subsequently re-install the libapache2-mod-php5 manually in order to restore functionality to our web server.

Please see the following github gist, it is a contiguous section of our server's dpkg.log showing the November 14, 2011 update to apache2:
https://gist.github.com/1368361
it includes

```
2011-11-14 11:22:18 remove libapache2-mod-php5 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
```

Is this a known issue?  Do other people see this too? I could not find any launchpad bug reports about it.

Platform details:

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
$ uname -srvm
Linux 2.6.38-12-virtual #51~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 29 20:27:50 UTC 2011 x86_64
$ dpkg -l | awk  '/ii.*apache/ {print $2 " " $3 }'
apache2 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
apache2-utils 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
apache2.2-bin 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
apache2.2-common 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
libapache2-mod-authnz-external 3.2.4-2+squeeze1build0.10.04.1
libapache2-mod-php5 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10
```

Thanks

At a high-level the update process looks like:

```
package package_name do
        action :upgrade
        case node[:platform]
        when 'centos', 'redhat', 'scientific'
                options '--disableplugin=fastestmirror'
        when 'ubuntu'
                options '-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"'
        end
end
```

But at a lower level

```
        def install_package(name, version)
          run_command_with_systems_locale(
            :command => "apt-get -q -y#{expand_options(@new_resource.options)} install #{name}=#{version}",
            :environment => {
              "DEBIAN_FRONTEND" => "noninteractive"
            }
          )
        end

        def upgrade_package(name, version)
          install_package(name, version)
        end
```

So Chef is using "install" to do "update".

This sort of moves the question around to "how does apt-get safe-upgrade" remember to re-install libapache-mod-php5?

The exact sequence of packages that triggered this was:

```
apache2
apache2-mpm-prefork
apache2-mpm-worker
apache2-utils
apache2.2-bin
apache2.2-common
```

But the code is attempting to run checks to make sure the packages in that list are installed already before attempting to "upgrade" them.

```
case node[:platform]
when 'debian', 'centos', 'fedora', 'redhat', 'scientific', 'ubuntu'
        # first primitive way is to define the updates in the recipe
        # data bags will be used later
        %w/
               apache2
               apache2-mpm-prefork
               apache2-mpm-worker
               apache2-utils
               apache2.2-bin
               apache2.2-common
        /.each{ |package_name|
                Chef::Log.debug("is #{package_name} among local packages available for changes?")
                next unless node[:packages][:changes].keys.include?(package_name)

                Chef::Log.debug("is #{package_name} available for upgrade?")
                next unless node[:packages][:changes][package_name][:action] == 'upgrade'

                package package_name do
                        action :upgrade
                        case node[:platform]
                        when 'centos', 'redhat', 'scientific'
                                options '--disableplugin=fastestmirror'
                        when 'ubuntu'
                                options '-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"'
                        end
                end

                tag('upgraded')
        }

        # after upgrading everything, run yum cache updater
        if tagged?('upgraded')
                # Remove old orphaned dependencies and kernel images and kernel headers etc.
                # Remove cached deb files.
                case node[:platform]
                when 'ubuntu'
                        execute 'apt-get -y autoremove'
                        execute 'apt-get clean'
                # Re-check what updates are available soon.
                when 'centos', 'fedora', 'redhat', 'scientific'
                        node[:packages][:last_time_we_looked_at_yum] = 0
                end
                untag('upgraded')
        end
end
```

But it's clear that it fails since the dpkg.log has

```
2011-11-14 11:22:25 install apache2-mpm-worker  2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
```

on a system which does not currently have apache2-mpm-worker.  I will have to discuss this with the author, thanks again.

Comment: I think the issue is we opted for "selective" package updates, i.e. we run "apt-get ... install" on each package name to be updated (via OpsCode Chef.)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that you are running the mpm-worker version of apache2, which does not like libapache2-mod-php5.

```
dpkg -l | grep apache2-mpm
```

You may wish to use apache2-mpm-prefork instead, which works better with mod_php5

Comment: I have added the package names and versions to the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you saved me a lot of time. :)